# Facebook OAuthException - #100) Invalid parameter

Tags: image, facebook, post

I am using facebook api for posting equirectangular image to the wall. I am able to post images upto 4 mb, but while uploading bigger equirectangular images I am getting following error;

OAuthException - #100) Invalid parameter

Although I am able to post bigger images on facebook wall manually. Here is my code.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(token);
client.Post("me/photos",
new
{
message = "test message",
url = "equirectangular image path of around 40 mb",
allow_spherical_photo = true
});
```

Please let me know if there is some size limit in api.

Thanks in advance,
Amar

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload larger than 4mb images via api.

Try compressing them on server side before uploading.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads